# Need help in Redirecting to another page

Tags: php

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Installation
  </title>
  <script src="public/js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="public/js/bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="public/js/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="public/js/bootstrap3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="public/js/bootstrap3/css/main.css">
 </head>
 <body>

  <div
   class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
   <div
    class="container">
    <div
     class="navbar-header">
     <button
      type="button"
      class="navbar-toggle"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span
       class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span
       class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span
       class="icon-bar"></span>
     </button>
     <a
      class="navbar-brand"
      href="<?php // echo base_url()?>">Kingpabel
      ATN</a>
    </div>
    <div
     class="navbar-collapse collapse">

    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
   </div>
  </div>
  <div
   class="rc">
   <div
    class="container main">
    <div
     class="col-md-3">

    </div>
    <div
     class="col-md-6">
     <form
      method="post"
      accept-charset="utf-8"
      role="form"
      class="form- signin form-horizontal">
      <h2
       class="form-signin-heading">Installation</h2>

      <div
       style="margin-top: 20px;">
       <label
        for="host_name"
        class="col-sm-3 control-label"
        style="color: black">
        Host
        Name
       </label>

       <div
        class="input text database_host  col-md-9">
        <input
         type="text"
         name="host_name"
         class="form-control"
         placeholder="Database Host Name"
         autofocus=""
         required="required"
         id="host_name">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div>
       <label
        for="database_name"
        class="col-sm-3 control-label"
        style="color: black">
        Database
        Name
       </label>

       <div
        class="input text database_name  col-md-9">
        <input
         type="text"
         name="database_name"
         class="form-control"
         placeholder="Database Name"
         autofocus=""
         required="required"
         id="database_name">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div>
       <label
        for="user_name"
        class="col-sm-3 control-label"
        style="color: black">
        User
        Name
       </label>

       <div
        class="input text user_name  col-md-9">
        <input
         type="text"
         name="user_name"
         class="form-control"
         placeholder="Database User Name"
         autofocus=""
         required="required"
         id="user_name">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div>
       <label
        for="password"
        class="col-sm-3 control-label"
        style="color: black">
        Password
       </label>

       <div
        class="input text password col-md-9">
        <input
         type="password"
         name="password"
         class="form-control"
         placeholder="Database Password"
         autofocus=""
         id="password">
       </div>
      </div>
      <div>
       <label
        for="project_url"
        class="col-sm-3 control-label"
        style="color: black">
        Project
        Url
       </label>

       <div
        class="input text project_url col-md-8 input-group input-group-sm">
        <input
         style="    margin-left: 13px;"
         type="text"
         name="project_url"
         class="form-control"
         placeholder="Project URL"
         autofocus=""
         id="project_url"
         aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
         <span
          class="input-group-btn">
          <button
           class="btn btn-default"
           type="button"
           style="margin-top: -15px;">/public</button>
         </span>
       </div>
      </div>

      <button
       type="submit"
       class="btn btn-lg btn-login btn-block">Install</button>
     </form>
    </div>

   </div>
  </div>
  <section
   id="bottom"
   style="margin-top: 50px">

  </section>
  <footer
   id="footer">
   <div
    class="container">
    <div
     class="footer">
     <div
      class="row">
      <div
       class="col-md-12">

      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>

   <?php
   if ($_POST) {
   $envFile = file_get_contents('.env');

   if (isset($_POST['host_name']) && $_POST['host_name'])
    $envFile = str_replace('DB_HOST=localhost', "DB_HOST=  {$_POST['host_name']}", $envFile);

    if (isset($_POST['database_name']) && $_POST['database_name'])
    $envFile = str_replace('DB_DATABASE=homestead', "DB_DATABASE={$_POST['database_name']}", $envFile);

    if (isset($_POST['user_name']) && $_POST['user_name'])
    $envFile = str_replace('DB_USERNAME=homestead', "DB_USERNAME={$_POST['user_name']}", $envFile);

    if (isset($_POST['password']) && $_POST['password'])
    $envFile = str_replace('DB_PASSWORD=secret', "DB_PASSWORD={$_POST['password']}", $envFile);

   file_put_contents('.env', $envFile);

  if (isset($_POST['project_url']) && $_POST['project_url']) {
    file_get_contents('index.php');
    file_put_contents('index.php', "<?php
  header('Location: {$_POST['project_url']}/public');
   ");

   }

    }`
```

In above code, after submitting the form, the idex.php is rewriiten and changes. And i wanted to redirect to another page after submitting the form. But it is not being redirected.

Comment: Start by reading what the manual for `header` says about generating output before calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what all your block of codes are for but perhaps try this..
On your

```
if (isset($_POST['project_url']) && $_POST['project_url']) {
    file_get_contents('index.php');
    file_put_contents('index.php', "<?php
    header('Location: {$_POST['project_url']}/public');
    ");
}
```

change to

```
if (isset($_POST['project_url']) && $_POST['project_url']) {
     $url = $_POST['project_url'] + '/public';
     header('Location: $url');
}
```